# How to get opacity current value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-10

I saw some topics about already, but none have a IE10 specific solution. I know IE10 follow W3C, but I couldn't find a "official w3c solution" either for getting current opacity value of a DOM Element. Below is the code I have so far (one pice from here, another from there...):

jGp.nau.padrao is a previous setting according with browser. Will be "ie" or "w3c". As long IE10 could be "w3c" in this case, it still a useful option for other functions I have in this library. Target is a DOM Element.

```
jGp.ee.getAlpha = function(target){
    if(jGp.nau.padrao=='w3c'){
        var temp_style = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(target,null); 
        if (!isNaN(temp_style.opacity)) { 
            opacityVal = temp_style.opacity; 
        } else if (!isNaN(temp_style.MozOpacity)) { 
            opacityVal = temp_style.MozOpacity; 
        } else {
            opacityVal = 1; // default value so my code will not crash
        }
        return parseFloat(opacityVal*100);
    } else {
        try {
            return target.filters.item('DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha').Opacity;
        } catch(e) {
            return 100; // default value so my code will not crash
        }
    } 
}
```

I can include IE versions, is previously detected too, I just need to define the right code for that. So far, this code works for FireFox, Chrome and Safari (I guess Opera too).

Comment: Why you're not using a framework like jquery? Then you can select opacity easy via $(target).css('opacity') and dont need to fit all the different browser properties

Comment: The initial purpose of not using jQuery was learning JavaScript. But now I'm really using my own library, depending on the case. Is a "micro Library" that I customize for my particular use.